# S subset of E. S bounded and closed but not compact

Tags: real-analysis

I was reading through the Rosenlicht Analysis Text and I could not think of a subset $S$ of metric space $E$ where $S$ is bounded and closed but not compact. Could someone give me an example of this and why it's true?
Thanks!

I was thinking that the subset $[0,1]$ of the metric space $R$ is closed and bounded however it is not compact.

Comment: maybe the set of two distinct points?

Comment: @EmilioNovati so like [0,1] right?

Comment: No! this is not a set with **only** two distict points

Comment: Isn't the set with the points from 0 to 1, [0,1] closed and bounded? How is [0,1] compact?

Comment: @SilverCat It depends on the metric.  We have a famous theorem (Heine Borel) that tells us in $\Bbb R^{n}$ with the Euclidean metric, a set is compact if and only if it is both closed and bounded.  $[0,1]$ is closed and bounded, so by the theorem it must be compact.

Comment: I supose that OP was thinking to the usual euclidean metric. Was not so? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Equip $\Bbb R$ with the discrete metric, i.e., $d(x,y) = \begin{cases} 0 & x = y \\ 1 & x \neq y \end{cases}$.

Then the interval $[0,1]$ is a subset of $\Bbb R$ which is closed (since its complement is open), bounded since $[0,1] \subseteq B(\frac{1}{2}, 2)$ (where $B(x,\epsilon)$ is the ball around $x$ of radius $\epsilon$), but the set is *not compact*, since the collection of singletons $\{x \}$ for each $x \in [0,1]$ is an open cover with no finite subcover.

Comment: Please don't accept this answer just yet.  Wait a short while for others to answer because someone might have some valuable input, or may produce a better answer.

Comment: Awesome so this would be the subset that is closed and bounded but not compact. Could we define a metric space that is closed and bounded and not compact that has the above subspace that is closed and bounded and not compact?

Comment: @SilverCat I mean, you could take the interval $[-5, 5]$ with the discrete metric.  It has as a subspace the example above, and neither the subspace nor it are compact, but both are closed and bounded.

Comment: Thank you! Makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 1):

$[0,1]\cap \mathbf Q$ is a bounded, closed subspace of the metric space $\mathbf Q$. However, it is not not compact since it is not complete.

Comment: You mean it's closed as a subspace of $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Well, it's a metric space. If you're in $\mathbf R^n$, a closed bounded subspace *is* compact.

Comment: I'm just filling in details that the OP may not know how to fill in, not questioning the validity of your answer.

Comment: @user46944: Oh! Sorry I misunderstood your comment. You're right, I'll add that.